# Android application compatibility with old APIs

Tags: android, android-studio

I created an app with the API 22 and I want to know if is necessary create a new project to make it compatible with the previous versions (for example with the API 19) or if I can do something simpler and efficient

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html#Versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using gradle just set the minSdkVersion to the number you'd like to use:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mypackage"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

in the app's build.gradle file

Comment: _targetSdkVersion 24_ is the last version?

Comment: Yes, always update targetSdk to whatever you have the latest. Make sure to update the SDK's frequently.

Comment: `targetSdkVersion 24 is the last version?` NO. It's the version the project uses to compile (hence, the `target` version). This **doesn't mean that it will not be compatible with future API** versions.

Comment: 24 is the latest API version, that doesnt meant it'll always be the latest.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 way,

**1)** Set your "minSdkVersion" from gradle file

> or

**2)** In Android Studio,

> File --> Project Structure --> app (on left menu) --> Flavors

then set "Min Sdk Version"

[image]